# How to use IBM Bluemix BMS mobile push notification service in an ionic.io project?

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Starting from here:

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush

I set up a new local cordova project from the git.

To use it with ionic.io I need two more files, package.json and ionic.config.json.

The missing package.json was added like this:

```
{
  "name": "exampleapp",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "ExampleApp: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ibm-mfp-push",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the missing ionic.config.json file with

```
{
  "name": "ExampleApp",
  "app_id": ""
}
```

Then I called

`ionic io init`

to add this one to my apps in ionic.io.

Next I created a new developer build profile in ionic.io in the new app containing all the apple credentials and provisioning profile information.

I added the bluemix application route and GUID to the index.js file. (Those came from the push service mobile settings dialog in bluemix).

Now with

`ionic package build ios --profile=dev`

I built the ios mobile app and downloaded it to iTunes to install it on my device.

The app installs without error, but does - nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the latest version of the newly released IBM Bluemix Cordova Push plugin, `bms-push`, rather than `ibm-mfp-push`. You will also need to run your application on an actual iOS device rather than the simulator to receive push notifications.

Adding `bms-push` will require some changes to the **AppDelegate** file. [Follow the instructions here](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push) to add `bms-push` to your project.

Comment: Since we want to use the ionic.io cloud build service (which is really a great help), the IBM docs do not help since there is no AppDelegate file that I can modify in this setup (AFAIK).

Comment: You have to modify the **AppDelegate** file after you compile the project for iOS (doing a `cordova build`) which would be a native change. If it's possible to download the code after you create an app with ionic.io, that's how you would make the changes.